# Boolean Addition Assignment in Python

Tags: python, boolean-logic

Instead of writing

`a = a or b`

for Booleans a and b, I would like to write something like:

`a |= b` (or equals)

but this doesn't work. Is there an equivalent to this concise statement in Python? Thanks.

Comment: You could do that. But |= DOES work, so...?

Comment: `a |= b` does work, please show an example where it doesn't

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. You're right.

Comment: Still very different. In the first example, `or` acts like a [null coalescing operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator) whereas `|` does bitwise or in the second one. Do print `3 or 5` and `3 | 5` and compare results.

Comment: `a |= b` works **iff** both are booleans. For everything else use `a = a or b`, or `a |= bool(b)` if `a` is a boolean.

Comment: There may be specific shortcuts for *certain types*, but really… is `a = a or b` really too long? It's explicit, obvious, simple and doesn't have any special cases to worry about. Terseness isn't the highest goal.

Comment: So in that case, is there an operator like `or=`?

Comment: @PProteus no there isn't. What's wrong with `a = a or b`?

Comment: Nothing really, except that it's pretty long if your variable names are descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that

```
a = a or b
```

Won't return a boolean per se, but will return `a` if evaluated truthy (so if it's -1, 1, "a", obj, etc)

`|` In python (and most languages) is a [Bitwise operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)

I'm afraid `a or b` is as short as it gets. But it's already much better than using ternary expression like in C

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

In Python

```
a = a if a else b
```